# No funciona carrusel, aparece una imagen debajo de otra

Tags: jquery

Tengo un carrusel en la portada y me aparece una imagen debajo de otra ypor supuesto no funciona:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function (e) { 
     $(this).insertAfter($(".modal-backdrop")); 
    });
$(document).on('click', '#acceso', function(){

    $('.modal-body').load('contentlogin.html',function(){
        $('#modallogin').modal('show');

    });
    
});
  $(function() {
    $('.tooltip-carousel').popover();

    $('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
      $('.tooltip-carousel').popover('hide');
      $(this).find('.caraousel-tooltip-item.active').fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      });
    });

    $('#carousel-example-generic').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
      var index = $(this).find('.carousel-inner > .item.active').index();
      $(this).find('.caraousel-tooltip-item').eq(index).fadeIn(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
      });
    });

    $('.tooltip-carousel').mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).popover('show');
    }).mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).popover('hide');
    });
 });  });
```

```css
.border{
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color:black;
    height:40px;
    }
#myModal{
    
    width: 100%;
}
.modal-lg {
    max-width: 65% !important;
}
*{padding: 0px ;}

#modallogin{

  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
float:left;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  transition: all .5s;

}
.modal-dialog{
    width:100%;
}

.modal-body{
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
}

li a{
   
 text-align: left;  
}

li a:hover{          
    background-color:#00A6D6;
    color: black;    
    
}
#nave ul{
        list-style: none;
        margin-left: 20px;
        height:8px;
      border-radius: 20px;
}
.btn-whatsapp {
        display:block;
        width:70px;
        height:70px;
        color#fff;
        position: fixed;
        right:20px;
        bottom:20px;
        border-radius:50%;
        line-height:80px;
        text-align:center;
        z-index:999;
}
#acceso:hover{
     background-color:#00A6D6;
    color: black;  
}
  body {
    background-color: #bbb;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
h2{
    font-size: 20px;
}
  
  .tooltip-carousel {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 11;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  
  .caraousel-tooltip-item {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .caraousel-tooltip-item.active {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <title>POOL ENTRERRIANO</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Fontawesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<!-- Bootstrap  JS-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->

<script src="index.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" media="screen" />
  </head>
  <body >
<header class="header-area fixed top">
   <div class="main-menu">
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container-fluid" >
            <ul class="nav" style="list-style: none;">
            <li><img src="favicon.ico" title="PORTADA" height="40"/></li>            
           <span class="border"> <li class="nav-item submenu dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i style="color: black;"class="fas fa-university"></i>INSTITUCIONAL</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">QUIENES SOMOS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li></span>           
               <span class="border"> <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i style="color: black;"class="fas fa-trophy"></i> TORNEOS</a></li></span>
               <span class="border"> <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i style="color: black;"class="fas fa-building"></i>SALAS</a></li></span>
               <span class="border"> <li class="nav-item"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/POOLENTRERRIANO/?ref=bookmarks" title="PAGINA OFICIAL DE FACEBOOK" class="nav-item nav-link" style="margin-right: 10px;"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f" >  </i></a></li>
                </span>
            </ul><ul class="nav" style="list-style: none;">
        <li class="nav-item"><a id="acceso" href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"> <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt">ACCESO</i></a></li>
   </ul>
        </div>
      </nav> </div>
</header>
      
        
   

<div class="btn-whatsapp">
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=543456472650" target="_blank">
<img src="http://s2.accesoperu.com/logos/btn_whatsapp.png" title="COMUNICATE CON NOSOTROS " alt=""/>
</a>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style=" vertical-align: central; width: 1500px;height:400px;">
    

    <!-- Indicators -->
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="gallery/1.jpg" alt="..."/>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h2>PODIO</h2> LOS 4 SEMIFINALISTAS!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="gallery/2.jpg" alt="..." />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h2>TROFEOS</h2> FOTO CON LOS TROFEOS
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="gallery/3.jpg" alt="..." />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h2>MARIO MEDINA</h2> TERCER PUESTO DE SAN JAIME
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
      </div>


    <!-- Controls -->
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>  </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

No puedo descubrir donde esta el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione cambiando el nombre de clase item por carrusel-item:

```html
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active" style="border-left: -100px;">
        <img src="gallery/1.jpg" alt="..." style="width: 1010px;height: 500px;"/>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h2>PODIO</h2> LOS 4 SEMIFINALISTAS!
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="gallery/2.jpg" alt="..." style="width: 1010px;height: 500px;"/>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h2>TROFEOS</h2> FOTO CON LOS TROFEOS
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="gallery/3.jpg" alt="..." style="width: 1010px;height: 500px;" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h2>MARIO MEDINA</h2> TERCER PUESTO DE SAN JAIME
        </div>
      </div>
```